# ETX characters (as L) showing up on websites

Tags: html, web, encoding

In the last few days I have had a couple of clients contact me saying that they are having some uppercase "L"'s appearing in places on their website. Upon investigating, I found that there were some random ETX characters on their websites. They are showing up on the websites on Windows (definitely on Chrome, maybe on other browsers too), but in Firefox on Mac I can see them in the source code. On Chrome on Mac I can't see them anywhere. Here are pictures of the problem:

[picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwOUQ.png)

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mkW7.png)

My clients websites have not been updated in months so I'm guessing that Windows pushed out an update in the last week to the default language/encoding which is making these show up now.

Removing them is easy, but I wanted to understand where they are coming from and how I can avoid the problem in the future. It looks like the characters are in text that I would have copied out of Photoshop. Is there any easy way to sanitise and remove these kind of characters when I copy from Photoshop or other similar programs?

As I mentioned earlier, I am on Mac, using Chrome primarily. Is there any way to get Chrome to actually show these characters so that I can see if they are appearing?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the issue is with Photoshop. Line breaks (Shift+Enter) are encoded in Photoshop as an `ETX` character (end of text), not an `LF` (line feed) or `CRLF` (carriage return + line feed).

These characters can be seen by pasting your content into a plain text editor such as [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/). The find/replace function should make removing them easy.

[image: Screenshot of Sublime Text displaying the ETX control character]

I don't believe there is any way to get the ETX characters to display in Chrome for Mac.

However, since the characters are still present (even if they are invisible), you could select all the text on the page (Mac: <kbd>Cmd+A</kbd> / Win:
 <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>) and paste it all into Sublime Text to find them.

Comment: This is my current solution to but I am wondering if anyone has an automated way of doing this? Or perhaps a setting that can convert the EXTs to spaces in Photoshop?